# Find and Replace contents outside of a bracket inside notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Example:

```
Barta (11858)
10531 (11831)
ATDooz(77) (15592)
=====As (1788)
魔 (1710)
```

Find and Replace filtered to:

```
11858
11831
15592
1788
1710
```

I need to delete everything outside of the parenthesis, however some of the lines have multiple sets of parenthesis, such as line 2. The Numbers I want to reduce it to will always be at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `/(?<=\()\d+(?=\)$)/gm` will do the trick. . Will match ending with `( + number + )`

Or, without lookbehind (for javascript): `/\d+(?=\)$)/gm`. Will match ending with `number + )`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1f4FWV/1

**EDIT**

To accomplish your task in n++ (replace all lines with the selected number), try to place your find criteria like that (changed a bit): `.*(((?<=\()\d+(?=\)$)))\)`, and, in the field `Replace with:`, : `\1`. And don't forget to check `Regular expression`.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that site, that's actually extremely helpful as a learning tool to be able to visualize each section.

With your solution however it is finding every number within the parenthesis, however I'm not sure what to put into the "Replace with" field to keep only the number.